# Foreign key always Null in DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I got this error in Spring: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqNhH.jpg) When I try to join two table entities.
And the foreign key is always Null in DB, Why?
My Entity Classes - Task, ListeExecJob.
Please, help me

Task :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name ="task")
public class Task implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;


@Column(name = "nom_job", length = 20,nullable = false)
private String nom_job;

@Column(name = "type_commande", length = 20,nullable = false)
private String type_commande;

@Column(name = "description", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String description;

@Column(name = "script", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String script;

@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
@Column(name = "date_execution")
private Date date_execution;

 @Column(name = "active")
 private boolean  active;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="id_liste")
 private ListeExecJob liste;


public ListeExecJob getListe() {
return liste;
}
public void setListe(ListeExecJob liste) {
this.liste = liste;
 }


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNom_job() {
    return nom_job;
}
public void setNom_job(String nom_job) {
    this.nom_job = nom_job;
}
public String getType_commande() {
    return type_commande;
}
public void setType_commande(String type_commande) {
    this.type_commande = type_commande;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getScript() {
    return script;
}
public void setScript(String script) {
    this.script = script;
}
public Date getDate_execution() {
    return date_execution;
}
public void setDate_execution(Date date_execution) {
    this.date_execution = date_execution;
}

public boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(boolean  active) {
    this.active = active;
}



public Task() {

}
public Task(Integer id, String nom_job, String type_commande, String description, String script,
        Date date_execution, boolean  active) {
    super();
    this.id=id;
    this.nom_job = nom_job;
    this.type_commande = type_commande;
    this.description = description;
    this.script = script;
   this.date_execution = date_execution;
    this.active=active ;

 }

}
```

ListeExecJob.java
     ____________________________________________________

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name ="liste")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
    value = {"dateCreation"},
    allowGetters = true
 ) 
public class ListeExecJob implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idListe")
private int idListe;


@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "date_creation")
@CreatedDate
private Date date_creation;

@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
@JoinColumn(name = "date_execution")
private Date date_execution;

@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
@Column(name = "fin_execution")
private Date fin_execution;

@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
@Column(name = "next_execution")
private Date next_execution;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="liste",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
 private List<Task> task;


public int getIdListe() {
    return idListe;
}

public void setIdListe(int idListe) {
    this.idListe = idListe;
}


public Date getDate_creation() {
    return date_creation;
}

public void setDate_creation(Date date_creation) {
    this.date_creation = date_creation;
}

public Date getDate_execution() {
    return date_execution;
}

public void setDate_execution(Date date_execution) {
    this.date_execution = date_execution;
}

public Date getFin_execution() {
    return fin_execution;
}

public void setFin_execution(Date fin_execution) {
    this.fin_execution = fin_execution;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@JsonIgnore
public List<Task> getTask() {

    if (task == null) {
        task = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    return this.task;
    }
 public void addTask(Task task) {
    getTask().add((Task) task);
    ((Task) task).setListe(this);
  }

 public void removeTask(Task task) {
    getTask().remove(task);
    task.setListe(null);
}


@JsonSetter
public void setTask(List<Task> task) {
    this.task = task;
}


public ListeExecJob() {

}

public ListeExecJob(int idListe, String status, Date date_creation, Date date_execution, Date b 
   fin_execution,
        Date next_execution) {
    super();
    this.idListe = idListe;
    this.status = status;
    this.date_creation = date_creation;
    this.date_execution = date_execution;
    this.fin_execution = fin_execution;
    this.next_execution = next_execution;
    }
  }
```

Task service

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.SUPPORTS)
@Primary
public class TaskService {

@Autowired
private TaskRepository repository;

@Autowired
private ListeExecJobService service;

@Autowired
public TaskService(TaskRepository repository) {
    super();
    this.repository = repository;
}

public List<Task> listAllTask(){
    return repository.findAll();
}
public Task addTask(Task task){

    ListeExecJob ab = service.getByreferenece(task.getListe().getIdListe());

    ab.addTask(task);
     return repository.save(task);

  /* task.setListe(ab);
     System.out.println(task.getListe().getIdListe());
    ab.addTask(task);*/
}

public Task updateTask(Integer id , Task task){
    Task job1 = new Task();
    job1 = task;
    job1.setId(id);
    return addTask(job1);
  }
  public void deleteTask(Integer id){
    repository.deleteById(id);
  }
  public Task getByreferenece(Integer id){
     return repository.findById(id).isPresent()? repository.findById(id).get():null;
  }
 }
```

ListeExecJobService

```
 @Service
 @Transactional
 @Primary
 public class ListeExecJobService {

@Autowired
private ListeExecJobRepository SJIRepos;

@Autowired
public ListeExecJobService(ListeExecJobRepository SJIRepos) {
    super();
    this.SJIRepos = SJIRepos;
}

 public List<ListeExecJob> listAllListeExecJob(){
        return SJIRepos.findAll();
    }
    public ListeExecJob addListeExecJob(ListeExecJob SJI){
       return SJIRepos.save(SJI);
    }
    public ListeExecJob getByreferenece(Integer idListe){
        return SJIRepos.findById(idListe).isPresent()? SJIRepos.findById(idListe).get():null;

    }
    public void deleteListeExecJob(Integer idListe){
        SJIRepos.deleteById(idListe);
    }


    public ListeExecJob updateListeExecJob(Integer idListe , ListeExecJob sji){
    ListeExecJob sji01 = new ListeExecJob();
    sji01 = sji;
    sji01.setIdListe(idListe);
    return addListeExecJob(sji01);
   }

   public void deleteById(Integer idListe) {
    SJIRepos.deleteById(idListe);
    }

   }
```

Comment: What line is TaskService 35?

Comment: Maybe you need to put a fetch=FetchType.EAGER in your @ManyToOne join.

Comment: public Task addTask(Task task){

  //35  ListeExecJob ab = service.getByreferenece(task.getListe().getIdListe());

    ab.addTask(task);
     return repository.save(task);

  /* task.setListe(ab);
     System.out.println(task.getListe().getIdListe());
    ab.addTask(task);*/
}

Comment: As Martin Fowler used to say "Never fix a bug until you write the test that fails!"  Have you a test that fails? :) Null for a column value is undefined in Oracle so will always evaluate to false in any kind of expression [except when the nvl function is used].

Comment: Try adding JsonBackRefernce and JsonManagedReference

Comment: I would suggest that you break that line out into multiple lines so you can see exactly where the NullPointer is coming from. Anything that comes before a "." could be null, causing your exception, so `service`, `task` and `task.getListe()`.

Comment: @MaxExplode I tried but nothing change

Comment: @bcr666 How can I solve it, please

Answer (score 0):

try @JoinColumn(name="id_liste",referencedColumnName = "idListe") in the task class, you have a problem in the join column